# How to divide container into different sets of columns in tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI in tkinter. So far I have reached this level.

[image]

The problem is, I am not able to centre the 4 buttons at the bottom, one of them is going out of the assigned width. This is because while making a top frame, I have assigned columnspan to be 3. If I make it 4 then the centring of the middle part goes off.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Steady State Data Processing')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(900, 500))


topFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'lavender', width = 900, height=100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
topFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3,  sticky="w")



labelCps = tk.Label(root, text='Cps', width = 0, height = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
labelIgn = tk.Label(root, text='Ign', width = 0, height = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
labelInj = tk.Label(root, text='Inj', width = 0, height = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)


labelCps.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky='we')
labelIgn.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky='we')
labelInj.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky='we')

cpsFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 300, height = 100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
cpsFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 0,  sticky="nsew")

ignFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 300, height = 100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
ignFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 1,  sticky="nsew")

injFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 300, height = 100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
injFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 2,  sticky="nsew")


labelAdv = tk.Label(cpsFrame, anchor = 'center', text='Cps adv threshold:') 
labelAdv.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')

entryAdv = tk.Entry(cpsFrame)
entryAdv.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'e')

labelIgn = tk.Label(ignFrame, justify = 'left', text = 'Dwell start threshold:') 
labelIgn.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
entryIgn = tk.Entry(ignFrame)
entryIgn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
labelIgn = tk.Label(ignFrame, anchor = 'center', text = 'Dwell end threshold:') 
labelIgn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entryIgn = tk.Entry(ignFrame)
entryIgn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

labelInj = tk.Label(injFrame, anchor = 'center', text = 'Inj start threshold:') 
labelInj.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
entryInj = tk.Entry(injFrame)
entryInj.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
labelInj = tk.Label(injFrame, anchor = 'center', text = 'Inj end threshold:') 
labelInj.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entryInj = tk.Entry(injFrame)
entryInj.grid(row = 1, column = 1)



root.grid_rowconfigure(3, pad = 50)

applyButton = tk.Button(root, text = 'Apply', padx = 30, pady = 15)
applyButton.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3)


text = ['Plot raw data', 'Plot tooth rpm', 'Plot cycle rpm', 'Plot ign data']
count = 0

for t in text:

    dataButton = tk.Button(root ,text = t, width = 5, height = 5 ,anchor = 'center', padx = 30, pady = 15)
    dataButton.grid(row = 4, column = count, sticky = 'news')
    # dataButton.grid_columnconfigure(count, weight = 2)    
    count = count + 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the blue section at the top? Is it supposed to be there, and not the full width of the window?

Comment: @BryanOakley That is a frame, which will be contained with widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the buttons, they need to be in a frame. Second, to make them fill the space allocated to them by grid, you have to configure the grid columns in the frame to expand. I'm not sure whether you wanted padding between the buttons, but I added some to the grid command.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Steady State Data Processing')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(900, 500))


topFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'lavender', width = 900, height=100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
topFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3,  sticky="w")



labelCps = tk.Label(root, text='Cps', width = 0, height = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
labelIgn = tk.Label(root, text='Ign', width = 0, height = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10) 
labelInj = tk.Label(root, text='Inj', width = 0, height = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)


labelCps.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky='we')
labelIgn.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky='we')
labelInj.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky='we')

cpsFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 300, height = 100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
cpsFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 0,  sticky="nsew")

ignFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 300, height = 100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
ignFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 1,  sticky="nsew")

injFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 300, height = 100, relief = 'raised') # , padx = 100, pady=100
injFrame.grid(row = 2, column = 2,  sticky="nsew")


labelAdv = tk.Label(cpsFrame, anchor = 'center', text='Cps adv threshold:') 
labelAdv.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')

entryAdv = tk.Entry(cpsFrame)
entryAdv.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'e')

labelIgn = tk.Label(ignFrame, justify = 'left', text = 'Dwell start threshold:') 
labelIgn.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'w')
entryIgn = tk.Entry(ignFrame)
entryIgn.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
labelIgn = tk.Label(ignFrame, anchor = 'center', text = 'Dwell end threshold:') 
labelIgn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entryIgn = tk.Entry(ignFrame)
entryIgn.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

labelInj = tk.Label(injFrame, anchor = 'center', text = 'Inj start threshold:') 
labelInj.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
entryInj = tk.Entry(injFrame)
entryInj.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
labelInj = tk.Label(injFrame, anchor = 'center', text = 'Inj end threshold:') 
labelInj.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
entryInj = tk.Entry(injFrame)
entryInj.grid(row = 1, column = 1)



root.grid_rowconfigure(3, pad = 50)

applyButton = tk.Button(root, text = 'Apply', padx = 30, pady = 15)
applyButton.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 3)


text = ['Plot raw data', 'Plot tooth rpm', 'Plot cycle rpm', 'Plot ign data']
count = 0

# Button frame
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='news', columnspan=4)
for t in text:

    # Expand the column widths as required by the window cavity.
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(count, weight=1)
    dataButton = tk.Button(frame ,text = t, width = 5, height = 5 ,anchor = 'center', padx = 30, pady = 15)
    dataButton.grid(row = 0, column = count, sticky = 'news', padx=30)
    # dataButton.grid_columnconfigure(count, weight = 2)    
    count = count + 1

root.mainloop()
```